# Error converting html to pdf with dompdf: Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, dompdf

I have a script that convert an html code with jpg and png images in PDF. Until this morning all worked right. After, without doing anything to the script or to the server it stop working and return this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `/tmp/ca_dompdf_img_AFNf9n' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544 in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.it/httpdocs/ldv/dompdf/lib/Cpdf.php:4862 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.it/httpdocs/ldv/dompdf/lib/Cpdf.php(4862): Imagick->__construct('/tmp/ca_dompdf_...') #1 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.it/httpdocs/ldv/dompdf/lib/Cpdf.php(4984): Cpdf->addImagePngAlpha('/tmp/ca_dompdf_...', 499.0142519685, 739.6242519685, 75, 75, 3) #2 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.it/httpdocs/ldv/dompdf/src/Adapter/CPDF.php(845): Cpdf->addPngFromFile('/tmp/ca_dompdf_...', 499.0142519685, 739.6242519685, 75, 75) #3 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.it/httpdocs/ldv/dompdf/src/Renderer/Image.php(110): Dompdf\Adapter\CPDF->image('/tmp/ca_dompdf_...', 499.0142519685, 27.265748031496, 75, 75, 'normal') #4 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.it/httpdocs/ldv/dompdf/src/Renderer.php(293): Dompdf\Renderer\Image->render(Object(Dompdf\FrameDecorator\Image)) #5 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.it/httpdocs/ldv/dompdf/src/ in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.it/httpdocs/ldv/dompdf/lib/Cpdf.php on line 4862
```

What may have happened?

Comment: I had the same error suddenly around the same time. Restarting Apache and PHP seems to have fixed it for me. Are you using Plesk by any chance? My working theory is that a Plesk auto update of some kind did something screwy, but I'm not sure hence posting this as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yes, I use Plesk. Now I haven't the server handy, I will try monday and I'll let you know.

Comment: Hello! I solved it, like you told me. Than you very much :-)

Answer (score 1):

Restart php. Make sure you restart the exact php version you run the project with. For example in Laravel you can find it on composer.json file. Then restart Apache.

It should solve this.

Answer (score 0):

@claudiog74
@udy-warnasuriya

in my case, restarting php-fpm solve the error

macos:
`brew services restart php@7.4`

ubuntu linux:
`sudo systemctl restart php7.4-fpm`